# do-while loop is not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, do-while

I cannot figure out why this is returning 1 instead of 7.

```
 const getNextEventCountTest = () => {

        
        let sum = 0;
        let q = 0;

        do {
            sum = sum + 0.5
        }
        while (sum < 4){
         
            q = q + 1;
        }

        return q;
  };
```

do-while is good here, since I want to always run the first code block but only conditionally increment q.

But this:

```
console.log(getNextEventCountTest()); => 1
```

whereas this has the right behavior:

```
const getNextEventCountTest = () => {
  
        let sum = 0;
        let q = 0;

        // this is desired behavior:
        while (sum < 4){
            sum = sum + 0.5
            if(sum < 4){
               q = q + 1;
            }
        }

        return q;
  };
```

Comment: Perhaps because your code executes like `do { ... } while(condition); { ... }`. Notice the added semicolon

Comment: ah yes, that's correct

Comment: The language perils of optional semi-colons.  It would be interesting to see what a good linter says about this code.

Comment: well it's been so long since I used a do-while lol, but the frankenstein construct I made up in OP has some value even though semantically it's a mess. Coincidentally intellij was forcing the braces after the while statement on a newline and I couldn't figure out why, now I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your code executes like `do { ... } while(condition); { ... }`. Notice the added semicolon - the second `{}` block executes once.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong regarding `do while` loop. Use this instead

```
do {
  //Your code that is to be executed
}
while(/* condition */);
```

I have improved the code for you;

```
const getNextEventCountTest = () => {
  let sum = 0, q = 0;

  // works only when sum and q are defined as an integer
  do{
     sum += 0.5
     if(sum < 4) q++;
  }
  while(sum < 4)
  return q;
}
```

Then, it will work as expected. Bye, have a great day!